# Problem after installing Flatpak 1.6.2

Tags: gnome, chromebook, crouton

I'm using Ubuntu 18.04 in Crouton on a Chromebook and I tried to install Flatpak. Everything went right while the installation, but I can't download anything from flathub and everytime I try to do something with flathub, it gives me an error.

Right now I tried to install the Spotify App, and It says

> Unable to install "com.spotify.Client from flathub": While trying to apply extra data: apply_extra script failed, exit status 256

I didn't found anything in the internet about that. I used [this tutorial](https://flatpak.org/setup/Ubuntu/) to install Flatpak 1.6.2 (if that's useful information).

What can I do?

Comment: What flatpak version do you have? `flatpak --version`. I've just installed it and installed spotify also on 19.10. Could give you my output during installation. I did not get your error message during it.

Comment: `sudo apt install flatpak` gives me the output:
(too long) https://pastebin.com/LhmvBWiK

Comment: You could also try `sudo apt install libostree-1-1 libflatpak0`

Answer (score 1):

What I've done to get it working on 19.10

```
$ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:alexlarsson/flatpak
$ sudo apt install flatpak
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  flatpak libostree-1-1

sudo apt install gnome-software-plugin-flatpak
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  gnome-software-plugin-flatpak libflatpak0

$ flatpak remote-add --if-not-exists flathub https://flathub.org/repo/flathub.flatpakrepo

Note that the directories 

'/var/lib/flatpak/exports/share'
'/home/spacer/.local/share/flatpak/exports/share'

are not in the search path set by the XDG_DATA_DIRS environment variable, so
applications installed by Flatpak may not appear on your desktop until the
session is restarted.

$ echo $XDG_DATA_DIRS
/usr/share/ubuntu-wayland:/usr/local/share:/usr/share:/var/lib/snapd/desktop

$ flatpak install flathub com.spotify.Client

Note that the directories 

'/var/lib/flatpak/exports/share'
'/home/spacer/.local/share/flatpak/exports/share'

are not in the search path set by the XDG_DATA_DIRS environment variable, so
applications installed by Flatpak may not appear on your desktop until the
session is restarted.

Looking for matches…
Required runtime for com.spotify.Client/x86_64/stable (runtime/org.freedesktop.Platform/x86_64/19.08) found in remote flathub
Do you want to install it? [Y/n]: 

com.spotify.Client permissions:
    ipc           network              pulseaudio          x11
    dri           file access [1]      dbus access [2]     bus ownership [3]
    tags [4]

    [1] xdg-music:ro, xdg-pictures:ro
    [2] org.freedesktop.Notifications, org.gnome.SessionManager,

        ID                                     Branch   Op   Remote    Download
 1. [✓] org.freedesktop.Platform.GL.default    19.08    i    flathub    93,1 MB / 92,6 MB
 2. [✓] org.freedesktop.Platform.Locale        19.08    i    flathub     3,2 MB / 318,2 MB
 3. [✓] org.freedesktop.Platform.VAAPI.Intel   19.08    i    flathub     8,6 MB / 8,7 MB
 4. [✗] org.freedesktop.Platform.openh264      19.08    i    flathub   594,2 kB / 593,4 kB
 5. [✓] org.gtk.Gtk3theme.Yaru-light           3.22     i    flathub   153,5 kB / 207,6 kB
 6. [✓] org.freedesktop.Platform               19.08    i    flathub   244,3 MB / 238,1 MB
 7. [✓] com.spotify.Client                     stable   i    flathub   135,7 MB / 131,9 MB

Warning: org.freedesktop.Platform.openh264 not installed
Installation complete.

$ flatpak install flathub org.freedesktop.Platform.openh264/x86_64/19.08

Note that the directories 

'/var/lib/flatpak/exports/share'
'/home/spacer/.local/share/flatpak/exports/share'

are not in the search path set by the XDG_DATA_DIRS environment variable, so
applications installed by Flatpak may not appear on your desktop until the
session is restarted.

Looking for matches…


        ID                                   Branch    Op    Remote    Download
 1. [✓] org.freedesktop.Platform.openh264    19.08     i     flathub   593,6 kB / 593,4 kB

Installation complete.

$ flatpak run com.spotify.Client

Note that the directories 

'/var/lib/flatpak/exports/share'
'/home/spacer/.local/share/flatpak/exports/share'

are not in the search path set by the XDG_DATA_DIRS environment variable, so
applications installed by Flatpak may not appear on your desktop until the
session is restarted.

/app/extra/bin/spotify: /app/lib/libcurl-gnutls.so.4: no version information available (required by /app/extra/bin/spotify)
Gtk-Message: 19:58:38.385: Failed to load module "atk-bridge"
Gtk-Message: 19:58:38.423: Failed to load module "canberra-gtk-module"
/app/extra/share/spotify/spotify: /app/lib/libcurl-gnutls.so.4: no version information available (required by /app/extra/share/spotify/spotify)
/proc/self/exe: /app/lib/libcurl-gnutls.so.4: no version information available (required by /proc/self/exe)
/proc/self/exe: /app/lib/libcurl-gnutls.so.4: no version information available (required by /proc/self/exe)
```

Spitify started successfully:
[image: spotify window]

Check commands starting from `$` sign if you've executed them.

Also, you could try creating new user:

```
sudo adduser newuser && sudo usermod -aG sudo newuser
```

log in with it and try again.

Comment: everything works until `flatpak install flathub com.spotify.Client`, the same error appears.

Comment: wait, i now did `sudo` before it, and I think it should work now. the error didn't appear

Comment: ahh, when I do `flatpak run com.spotify.Client` it says `error: Idconfig failed, exit status 256`

Comment: @blubiboy98 Try to create new user, login with it and try again. Also, what desktop environment do you have?

Comment: ok i'll try it, and i use gnome

Comment: After that try also `flatpak repair`